# Closing <link> tag ignored by JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I have an HTML document that I receive as String and then I parse this using jSoup.
This HTML document (in the string form) contains `<link>` tags as follows -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
```

and this is how im parsing it -

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

where `html` is an HTML document in the form of a string.

After parsing when I print `doc`, everything remains the same apart from `<link>` tag which changes to -

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
```

Please note that the closing slash is absent here.
Also note that if the original string contains `<link>` tag in the following form -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"></link>
```

The result is still the same ,ie, `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">` 
Why is Jsoup doing this and how do I prevent this from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it actually changing the `href` of the link, or are you just referring to the missing `/`?

Comment: @jurgemaister Im sorry. I made an error in copying the data. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to avoid modification of tags, try this:

```
Document htmldoc = Jsoup.parse(html, baseuri, Parser.xmlParser());
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [HTML5 spec on the `<link>` element:](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element)

> Tag omission in text/html:
>   No end tag.

So the spec says there shouldn't be an end tag. The spec allows end tag to void elements, but it's not the default. I'm guessing Jsoup follows the HTML spec.